# NULL values on access

Tags: ms-access

When I copy row of my table and when I paste it all empty string values are replaced by NULL value.I try to uninstall acces and install I have the same problem.

For example here I copy/paste the same oh the same table on access and when I opened it with DBeaver software and there are NULL values

DBeaver data

[image: 1]

Have you ever have this problem and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Maybe don't allow empty string in text fields. I don't. Why would there be empty strings to begin with? Are you sure the original record has empty string in fields?

Comment: @June7- I would have thought that the trick would be `Required=Yes` and `Allow_Zero_Length=Yes`.

Comment: @GordThompson, just because Allow_Zero_Length is set to allow ZLS doesn't mean there has to be, Null is also allowed. So why would data entry process result in entry of ZLS?

Comment: because `Required=Yes` is `NOT NULL`, so that should prevent `''` from being interpreted as NULL.